# Validating form posts with php and ajax

Tags: php, security, validation, xss, sql-injection

I have a form in Extjs that is submitting data via POST to my controller. The user is authenticated in the constructor of my controller when the data is submitted. But how do i make sure the user is submiting data for something he is allowed to change. Example...

Tim is the user.
Tim is going to edit his 'group description'. In the form i will have his groupid to tell my function what 'group' to edit. What if Tim decided to play a prank on his friend Robbert and change the groupid to Robberts group id and edit the description.

My Question
Will i have to select the 'groupid' and its permissions along with the users authenticated data and compare to validate that Tim is the owner of the group? Do i need to create some type of POST secrect md5 value? Is their an easier way

What if someone POSTs data from some other server to my server?

Im glad i have the internet to ask stupid questions :) Thanks

Comment: Just verify that the user has permission, no need to do anything crazy with secret values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will i have to select the 'groupid' and its permissions along with the users authenticated data and compare to validate that Tim is the owner of the group?

Yes, that would be the normal way to do an authorisation check. It is not especially onerous.

> Do i need to create some type of POST secrect md5 value?

Not for authorisation's sake. When you need to issue a token that confers authorisation at a later time you would generally use a timestamped HMAC of some sort. But there's no need for that here, just check that the user is authorised to perform the action they are requesting, at the time they request it.

You probably do need to create some type of POSTed secret for the purposes of protection against cross-site request forgery, but that would be a different question. It would not normally interact with the question of authorisation.

Comment: Ah ok. Would best practices dictate i recreate my 'Group' object and validate from the recreated object or just use a query directly in my model to verify the user can edit the object('Group')?

Comment: How you implement the authorisation check isn't critical in itself, but in general you want to re-use the same code to check permissions both at the time of carrying out an action, and at the time of deciding whether or not to show the link/button/etc leading to the action. Otherwise you end up with inconsistencies hiding unwanted execution opportunities.